# Regarding /proc/interrupts what are MIS and ERR?

Tags: linux, proc, interrupt

Playing aroud looking at /proc/interrupts The output below shows ERR and MIS on lines 26 and 27 respectively. What are these and why do they have counts (albeit of zero) for CPU0 but no others, as well as no description? Am I right to think they're actually to do with if the PIC errors itself?

Thanks ErikF for the reply. Why do these interrupts only appear for CPU0? Is it because only that CPU will receive an interrupt if there is an error with the PIC/Interrupt System?

```
    1.  username@domain:/proc$ cat interrupts  
    2.             CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7  
    3.    0:    1221738          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer  
    4.    1:          9          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042  
    5.    6:          3          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   6-edge      floppy  
    6.    8:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0  
    7.    9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi  
    8.   12:        169          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042  
    9.   14:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC  14-edge      ata_piix  
    10.  15:         96      65508          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC  15-edge      ata_piix  
    11. NMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts  
    12. LOC:        402        123        273         78        134        110        118        110   Local timer interrupts  
    13. SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts  
    14. PMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts  
    15. IWI:         95         83         81         94         90         97         86         76   IRQ work interrupts  
    16. RTR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries  
    17. RES:    2769117    3625540    1918695    3115064    2249434    2089381    1783180    2173439   Rescheduling interrupts  
    18. CAL:       3468      22419      21729      15320      20704      31602      15100      18188   Function call interrupts  
    19. TLB:      11579      12003      12034      10741      10855      11647       9593      11018   TLB shootdowns  
    20. TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts  
    21. THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts  
    22. DFR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts  
    23. MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions  
    24. MCP:        224        224        224        224        224        224        224        224   Machine check polls  
    25. HYP:    2620495    2791215   12310023    2806541    2615199    1920111    2463082    2627540   Hypervisor callback interrupts  
    26. ERR:          0  
    27. MIS:          0  
    28. PIN:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event  
    29. PIW:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

Comment: The reason that the `ERR` and `MIS` stats only have a single entry is that they're not actually CPU stats, but events belonging to the IO-APIC controller itself (`ERR` for errors on the bus, `MIS` for an edge/level mismatch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct: they relate to the IO-APIC system. `ERR` is documented in the kernel documentation [in `Documentation/filesystems/proc`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) (lines 677-680):

> `ERR` is incremented in the case of errors in the IO-APIC bus (the bus
>   that connects the CPUs in a SMP system. This means that an error has
>   been detected, the IO-APIC automatically retry the transmission, so it
>   should not be a big problem, but you should read the SMP-FAQ.

AFAICT you shouldn't see this unless there is a hardware issue. As the documentation indicates, it's something that you show note and investigate if it happens frequently.

`MIS` doesn't show up in the documentation, but [this Gentoo forum message from 2005](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-348925-start-0.html) talks about it. [The current `arch/x86/apic/io_apic.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/apic/io_apic.c) (lines 1797-1806) has the following comment:

> It appears there is an erratum which affects at least version 0x11 of
>   I/O APIC (that's the 82093AA and cores integrated into various
>   chipsets).  Under certain conditions a level-triggered interrupt is
>   erroneously delivered as edge-triggered one but the respective IRR bit
>   gets set nevertheless.  As a result the I/O unit expects an EOI
>   message but it will never arrive and further interrupts are blocked
>   from the source.  The exact reason is so far unknown, but the
>   phenomenon was observed when two consecutive interrupt requests from a
>   given source get delivered to the same CPU and the source is
>   temporarily disabled in between.

As this comment (and code) haven't significantly changed in over 10 years (other than kernel restructuring), I'm not sure how relevant it is today, but it is very small and protects against a strange hardware quirk.

The files that I looked at were from version 4.15.10 of the kernel. Your sources may vary.